# How is the lifetime of a struct with a borrowed value as member affected by this borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct that contains some values as a starting point, see the following [working code snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d58d0c120c5dbc668a992915d975c179):

```rust
struct SomeBigStructWithValues {
    values: Vec<isize>,
    other_big_crazy_stuff: usize,
}

impl SomeBigStructWithValues {
    fn merge(&mut self, other: &Self){
        for (_i, val) in other.values.iter().enumerate() {
            self.values.push(val-0);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = SomeBigStructWithValues { values: vec![0, 1], other_big_crazy_stuff: 1<<10 };
    loop {
        let b = SomeBigStructWithValues { values: vec![2, 3, 4], other_big_crazy_stuff: 1<<10 };
        a.merge(&b);
        break;
    }
    println!("{:?}", a.values);
}
```

First of all, I found it interesting to see, that the borrow checker compiles this, because `b` only lives inside the loop, but the `merge` call uses `b` to modify `a.values` which is accessed outside the loop. I suspect, that the borrow checker understands, that inside the `merge` call only a copy from `b.values` happens, and no borrowing from `b` is needed after the `merge`.

Now I want to add a reference/borrow to a config object. Sadly, this [breaks compilation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b955a4133e85b4cbd8b1a9c79aa4fb1c). The borrow checker sees the config object inside the loop and complains about its lifetime when using `a.values` even though the config itself is not accessed inside the `merge` call. I am quite new to rust and do not understand the difference in these two cases the compiler seems to make. Is there some lifetime annotation that would make this work? Any pointers and explanations of this behavior would be greatly appreciated!

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Config{}

const ConfigA: Config = Config{};
const ConfigB: Config = Config{};

struct SomeBigStructWithValues<'a> {
    globals: &'a Config,
    values: Vec<isize>,
    other_big_crazy_stuff: usize,
}

impl SomeBigStructWithValues<'_> {
    fn merge(&mut self, other: &Self){
        for (_i, val) in other.values.iter().enumerate() {
            self.values.push(val-0);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = SomeBigStructWithValues { globals: &ConfigA, values: vec![0, 1], other_big_crazy_stuff: 1<<10 };
    loop {
        let localConfig = ConfigB.clone();
        // code that changes localConfig
        let b = SomeBigStructWithValues { globals: &localConfig, values: vec![2, 3, 4], other_big_crazy_stuff: 1<<10 };
        a.merge(&b);
        break;
    }
    println!("{:?}", a.values);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0597]: `localConfig` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:52
   |
24 |         let localConfig = ConfigB.clone();
   |             ----------- binding `localConfig` declared here
25 |         // code that changes localConfig
26 |         let b = SomeBigStructWithValues { globals: &localConfig, values: vec![2, 3, 4], other_big_crazy_stuff: 1<<10 };
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
29 |     }
   |     - `localConfig` dropped here while still borrowed
30 |     println!("{:?}", a.values);
   |                      -------- borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Self` is `SomeBigStructWithValues` with the same lifetime parameter as `&self` therefore you force the internal lifetimes of `self` and `other` to be the same, but since `a` is accessible and accessed after the block `b.globals` would have to bee too.
It's easily fixed by not implicitly reusing the same lifetime for `other` and `self`, just replace `Self` which is the exact same as the type of `self` including the lifetime parameter with the same type, but without being bound to the same lifetime, `SomeBigStructWithValues`:

```rust
    fn merge(&mut self, other: &SomeBigStructWithValues){
        for (_i, val) in other.values.iter().enumerate() {
            self.values.push(val-0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this precise answer. I suspected that it had something to do with the implicit lifetime labeling, but did not know that `Self` not only is an alias for the struct name, but also the lifetime parameter. I actually tried using `fn merge<'b>(&'_ mut self, other: &'b Self)` as signature, but that gave the same error. Do you know if it is because the lifetime error gets precedence over a type having two lifetime parameters, or are two lifetime parameters (here implied `'_` and labeled `'b` for `Self`) actually allowed? Why would two parameters be allowed?

Comment: The lifetimes in that signature don't apply to the inner lifetime of `SomeBigStructWithValues`, only to the references themselves so it's allowed of course, but those are just the same, distinct lifetimes that would be elided otherwise. And yes, `Self` is always the exact same type as in the `impl` line, including all type and lifetime parameters.